# Add KML to Google Maps by querying database in asp.net page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, kml

I created an asp.net web page (C# .NET 4.5.1 web application) and added a google map to it that centers on the user's current location, adds a weather overlay, and all is working fine.  As this is a solution for pilots I want to add their route for today.  I have to query the database for today's routes and then put the KML data on the map.  I'm not overly well versed in javascript or jquery as I'm learning this.  I can create a method in the code behind that returns the KML and/or geocoords for today's route but I'm not sure how to get that to the google map.

If anyone could help in how to go about this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a .ashx script handler page that returns the KML and the URL to this page is set in the kml layer options.  One note is that the location of this .ashx page has to allow anonymous access if your site is locked down to logged in users only.